# Lighttpd, PHP errors generate error 500

Tags: php, lighttpd

If I have an error in the PHP code, Lighttpd gives a 500 error and a line like this

`mod_fastcgi.c.2676) FastCGI-stderr: PHP Parse error:`...

appears in the log.

The php.ini (/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini) has the following lines:

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

I'd like to see the errors in the browser, not in the log of the web server.

Comment: In the future, please try a quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+display+errors+in+browser) before posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set `display_errors` to `On`in your `php.ini` file:

```
display_errors = On
```